# setInterval crashes my browser when running a user script?

Tags: javascript, crash, setinterval, userscripts

Okay so the script works but setInterval keeps crashing my browser after 30secs or so.
At least I think that's what's happening.

Here's the code:

```
var count = 0;

setInterval(function()
{
    var ifLose = document.getElementById('result-text').innerHTML;

    if (ifLose.length > 4) 
    {

        count++;
        document.getElementById("bet-multiplier").click();
        document.getElementById("bet-bt").click();

    }
    else 
    {
        for (count > 0; count--;) 
        {

        document.getElementById("bet-divider").click();

        }

        document.getElementById("bet-bt").click();

    }   
}, 1000);
```

What am I doing wrong?
Does it have something to do with count and the for loop?
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is your problem (or at least a big part of the problem):

```
    for (count > 0; count--;)
```

After the first time the timer handler runs, "count" will be -1.  This loop will just keep going for a really long time.

You probably want

```
    for (; count > 0; count--)
```

The `for` loop header has three parts: initialization, test, and ... uhh, the third part, which is traditionally where you do iteration control but which really is just a place to put an expression. Your original code had the test expression first.  That's not *syntactically* incorrect, because JavaScript just expects an expression, and a comparison expression like that is fine as far as that goes. It doesn't really do anything, however.  The test expression in your version was `count--`, which is also syntactically OK and not a bad thing for a test expression. However, because the interval handler never resets "count" to `0`, once it's decremented it to -1 the loop will keep going.

Comment: Thank you! This fixed it for me :D
So it was just a problem in my syntax!
Could you please explain the difference between this line and the one I had originally? I'm unsure why count will be -1 in my original code

Comment: @user1115155 OK, I'm adding a little to the answer.

Comment: Thanks that makes way more sense! 
You helped me a lot!